# IoC vs Services/Singletons

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to understand the value of IoC containers, injecting dependencies into the requiring types instead of using the more classic approach of having static services or singletons.

**The question**: What are the clear advantages of using an IoC container?

From what I know:

**Advantages:**

- Single point of configuration
- Improved application testability (e.g. Moq framework)
- Easier to deal with change (Not depending on a concrete types, but rather interfaces allows for easier change control - e.g. swapping logging service should not require application-wide code changes)

**Disadvantages:**

- Learning curve
- More interfaces?

Here is a code example of both:

```
// Statics & singletons
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Service.DoSomething(); // static method call
        Singleton.Instance.DoSomething(); // singleton method call
    }
}

// IoC
public class MyClass
{
    IService service;
    IAnotherService anotherService;

    // Depencies are injected by an IoC container..
    public MyClass(IService service, IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        service.DoSomething();
        anotherService.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason #1.  It enhances modularity by decoupling components.   By introducing a common interface, two software components and provide and consume a service through the common interface.  You can easily swap providers without breaking your consumers.

Reason #2  Testability.  Imagine 'Service' and 'AnotherService' are full-blown systems like a mapping service.    When you create unit tests for your class you want your unit tests to be as simple and as self-contained as possible.   With IoC, you can substitute your own dumbed-down implementation of Service and AnotherService in your unit tests.